# Torsors in the analytic topology versus torsors in the etale topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, stacks, reductive-groups

Let $S= \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb C}$ be the affine line, and let $G$ be a smooth connected reductive group over $S$, e.g., $G = \mathbb G_m, \mathrm{SL}_n$ or $SO_n$.

Is every analytic $G$-torsor over $S$ algebraic?

In other words, is the set $H^1_{et}(S,G)$ in bijection with the set of holomorphic $G$-torsors over $\mathbb C$ (via the natural map)?

In yet other terms: is every holomorphic morphism of analytic stacks $\mathbb C\to BG^{an}$ induced by a unique morphism of algebraic stacks $S\to BG$?

If the answer is negative, are there any positive results in this direction?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but for trivial reasons.  By the Grauert-Oka principle, every analytic torsor over $\mathbb{C}$ is trivial.

Comment: But already if you replace the line with a punctured elliptic curve, the statement is no longer true: every analytic torsor is trivial, while a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor may be algebraically non-trivial.